# Are files in my Swift project hidden during release?

Tags: ios, swift

In my Swift project I created a folder(group) called 'configuration' and inside of there another folder called 'levels'. This is in my actual Swift project on the navigation tree with all of my actual Swift files.

In this folder I created a bunch of JSON configuration files to configure my levels at runtime dynamically. Some of these levels (thus config files) are considered 'premium content' meaning it's not initially unlocked until either a certain time of the year or if you get some achievements.

I was concerned that a hacker could read these JSON files through ifunbox or something else, but I wasn't sure. If they could, then they could swap the premium ones with the non-premium ones to access them earlier than intended.

If I were to release my app on the App Store, do all files that are inside of my Swift project become bundled away and generally unable to be read?

I know that .swift files are (the actual source code) but what about other resources/assets that are alongside of my .swift project (albeit in little folders)?

Thanks!

Comment: just unzip the ipa file and check it

Comment: They weren't visible, which is good!

Comment: Check, http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/securing-and-encrypting-data-on-ios--mobile-21263 and https://realm.io/news/conrad-kramer-reverse-engineering-ios-apps-lyft/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

They appear to be inaccessible from the basic attempts I made. Did not try jail breaking but if anyone knows please share! Thanks.